# Assigning to columns in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

How could the following MATLAB code be written using NumPy?

```matlab
A = zeros(5, 100);
x = ones(5,1);
A(:,1) = x;
```

Assigning to rows seems to work easily, but I couldn't find an example of assigning an array to a column of another array.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `a[:,1] = x[:,0]`.  You need `x[:,0]` to select the column of `x` as a single numpy array.  If you have the choice of how to format `x`, it's better to not make it a 2-dimensional array in the first place, but just a regular (row) array:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> x = numpy.ones(5)
>>> x
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> a[:,1] = x
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: `a[:,1]` means all elements of column 1. See numpy [Basic Slicing and Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing).

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> A = np.zeros((5,100))
>>> x = np.ones((5,1))
>>> A[:,:1] = x
```