# Why can't I assign an array as column of another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this numpy array

```
data = np.array([10.66252794 10.65999505 10.65745968 10.65492432 10.65239142 10.64985606
 10.64732069 10.64478533 10.64225243 10.63971707 10.6371817  10.6346488
 10.63211344 10.62957807 10.62704518 10.62450981 10.62197445 10.61944155
 10.61690619 10.61437082])
```

I want the values in data to be in the p-th column of the array result.

Just to clarify, I want to achieve the same as Matlab's `result(:,p)`

I tried

```
result[..., p] = data
```

but this gives me

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20) into shape ()
```

Isn't numpy's `result[..., p]` the same as Matlab's `result(:,p)`

I also tried what it's been suggested here [Assigning to columns in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923212/assigning-to-columns-in-numpy)

But `result[...,p] = data[..., 0]` puts in `result` only the first value of `data` which is `10.66252794`

Comment: If `result` is 2d then `result[:, p] = data` should set data as the pth column

Comment: result is 1D, in fact print(result.shape) gives me (20,)

Comment: Then it doesn't have any columns... so how do you want to update its pth column?

Comment: I was wrong, data is 1D, while result is an empty array. All of the code is in a for loop and p is the counter, so for each iteration the column that gets data values assigned to changes

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a column to an apparently empty array. You can only assign data of shape (20,) to any column in result if result is an array with mxn rows and columns, such that the number of rows, m = 20. Like:

```
result = np.zeros((20,5))
result[:,0] = data #Assigning to column 0
```