# Set the value of an entire column in one line of code

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I was doing the problem "Given a matrix, A of size M x N of 0s and 1s. If an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0". So I am stuck at how to change the value of the entire column contatining the value 0.

```
def setZeroes(self, A):
        r=len(A)
        c=len(A[0])
        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                if (A[i][j]==0):
                    A[i]=[0 for j in range(c)]
                    A[0:r][j]=[0][j]
```

I know this is a bad implementation but I just want to know how to set the value of an entire column for the matrix to be zero.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a practical application for this. Can you give an example, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923212/assigning-to-columns-in-numpy

Comment: You can use a `numpy.ndarray` for the matrix then, transpose, set a row to ‘0’, then re-transpose.  But @Michael link is better.

Comment: if you use normal list then you will have to use `for`-loop : `for y in range(r): A[y][j] = 0`

Comment: BTW: in similar way you can write for row - `for x in range(c): A[i][x] = 0`

Comment: I see one problem with your function - when you change values in columns/rows in original array then in next loop will see new zeros so it will replace values in other rows. You may have to duplicate array and search zeros in duplicate array but change values in original array.

Answer (score 0):

If you use normal list then you will have to use `for`-loop :

```
 for y in range(r): 
     A[y][j] = 0
```

and similar way you can write code for row

```
 for x in range(c): 
     A[i][x] = 0
```

so you would need

```
 if A[i][j] == 0:
     for y in range(r): 
         A[y][j] = 0 
     for x in range(c): 
         A[i][x] = 0
```

But I see other problem with your code. You check zeros in the same array in which you change values so after changing values in row/column you will have new zeros which will generate new changes.

For example

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 0, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
```

I would expect zeros only in middle row and middle column

```
[
    [1, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [7, 0, 8]
]
```

but it creates

```
[
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```

because after putting zeros in middle row and middle column it will use these zeros to generate new zeros in next rows and columns.

You would have to duplicate original array and check zeros in duplicated array but change values in original array

```
import copy

def setZeroes(A):
    temp = copy.deepcopy(A)
    r = len(A)
    c = len(A[0])
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            if temp[i][j] == 0:
                #A[i] = [0 for j in range(c)]
                for x in range(c):
                    A[i][x] = 0
                for y in range(r):
                    A[y][j] = 0
                    
a = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 0, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

print(a)
setZeroes(a)
print(a)
```

Or you should first find all zeros in array and after that change values in array.

```
def setZeroes(A):
    r = len(A)
    c = len(A[0])
    
    pos = []
    
    # find all zeros 
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            if A[i][j] == 0:
                pos.append( (i,j) )
                
    # change it
    for i, j in pos:
        for x in range(c):
            A[i][x] = 0
        for y in range(r):
            A[y][j] = 0

a = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 0, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

print(a)
setZeroes2(a)
print(a)
```