# Why do my numpy constructs ignore tuple deconstruction?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, iterable-unpacking

edit: Let me clarify the mystery variables from original post

Assign some variables

```
WHITE = 0 #UP
BLUE = 1 #DOWN
ORANGE = 2 #LEFT
GREEN = 3 #FRONT
RED = 4 #RIGHT
YELLOW = 5 #BACK
```

First, I create a janky matrix:

```
cube = np.array([
        np.array([
          np.array([WHITE, WHITE, WHITE]),np.array([WHITE, WHITE, WHITE]), np.array([WHITE, WHITE, WHITE])
        ]),
        np.array([
         np.array([BLUE, BLUE, BLUE]), np.array([BLUE, BLUE, BLUE]), np.array([BLUE, BLUE, BLUE])
        ]),
        np.array([
         np.array([ORANGE, ORANGE, ORANGE]), np.array([ORANGE, ORANGE, ORANGE]), np.array([ORANGE, ORANGE, ORANGE])
        ]),
        np.array([
         np.array([GREEN, GREEN, GREEN]), np.array([GREEN, GREEN, GREEN]), np.array([GREEN, GREEN, GREEN])
        ]),
        np.array([
         np.array([RED, RED, RED]), np.array([RED, RED, RED]), np.array([RED, RED, RED])
        ]),
        np.array([
         np.array([YELLOW, YELLOW, YELLOW]), np.array([YELLOW, YELLOW, YELLOW]), np.array([YELLOW, YELLOW, YELLOW])
        ])
      ])
```

The np.arrays are one of my attempts at debugging.

Next, I attempt to swap columns, rows, etc. with tuple deconstruction:

```
rubiks[LEFT][:,2], rubiks[DOWN][0] = rubiks[DOWN][0], rubiks[LEFT][:,2]
```

The result is as if it were applied iteratively:

```
[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[2 2 1]
  [2 2 1]
  [2 2 1]]
```

It should be:

```
[[2 2 2]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[2 2 1]
  [2 2 1]
  [2 2 1]]
```

I assume I am misunderstanding something, but shouldn't this swap the values like intended?

Comment: you've got a lot of undefined variables in there

Comment: but if you're trying to assign values to slices, I think you're just going to have to do it one at a time

Comment: Assigning values to slices is very possible using numpy, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923212/assigning-to-columns-in-numpy for syntax

Comment: Furthermore, swapping just rows in this method produces an identical incorrect result

Comment: Exactly, one slice at a time

Comment: You're still missing some variable definitions, btw

Comment: The problem is this is for ML, sure I can make a variable to copy to and from, but it's going to get ran a LOT. I'd much prefer to use the intended python method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slicing on the right side generates references (or 'view' in numpy's terminology). If you force a copy, you can get the expected behavior.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2])
a[:1], a[1:] = a[1:], a[:1]
print(a) # [2 2]

import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2])
a[:1], a[1:] = a[1:].copy(), a[:1].copy()
print(a) # [2 1]
```

Multi-variable assignment is essentially a tuple packing & unpacking. Numpy slice at the right side of an assignment expression will only provide a reference instead of a copy **at the time when the right-side tuple is made**. When the second assignment take effect, the underlying storage of `a` has already been modified.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

In general, avoid figuring out if a numpy slice would automatically be a copy. Take a copy when it is logically necessary.

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed, I wasn't aware np did references, explains some other unexpected behaviours i've seen

Comment: Glad it helped :)